How can I enable typescript linting in my eslint.config.mjs file
First time trying to add linting to my node project- possibly an easy fix I'm missing...
I have been struggling to enable linting for typescript files in my project, running npx eslint . gives me lint errors for my index.js file only. I made another file called app.ts with some lint errors but these dont seem to get picked up
app.ts file
--------------
import fs from 'fs';
const path = require('path')

const num1 = 42;

function greet(name){
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}`);
}

function processInput(input: any){
    return input;
}

greet("User")


eslint.config.mjs file
------------------------
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";


/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config[]} */
export default [
  // Javascript files configurations
  { files: ["**/*.js"], languageOptions: { sourceType: "commonjs" , globals: globals.browser },
    plugins: { js: pluginJs },
    rules: {
      // List of recommended rules applied can be found on the following link with a green tick marker https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/
      ...pluginJs.configs.recommended.rules,

      //Enable a rule, if triggered exit code '1'
      //"no-duplicate-imports": "error",

      // Disable rules with 'off'
      //"no-unused-vars": "off",
      
      // Change errors to warnings with 'warn', does not affect exit code
      //"no-undef": "warn",
      
      // Add other rules
      //"semi": "warn",
    }
  },

  // Typescript files configurations
  { files: ["**/*.ts"], languageOptions: { sourceType: "module", globals: globals.browser, parser: tseslint.parser },
    plugins: { ts: tseslint.plugin },
    rules: {
      ...tseslint.configs.recommended.rules,

      // Add or override rules for Typescript
      //"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error"
    },
  },
];

// Fix all possible errors using --fix in CL (eg. -npx eslint . --fix) or npm run lint


Running npx eslint .
/home/user/DevOps/Training/stratus-node-linting-playground/index.js
  11:15  error  'x' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Have you read through the typescript-eslint docs on https://typescript-eslint.io? There's a 'getting started' guide that suggests an ESLint config different from yours.

I have tried the getting started code but the ts lints also parse the js files as well so under index.js I would get something like @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports
